# Unicode strings in my C# App are shown with question marks

Tags: c#, string, unicode, encoding, c++-cli

I have a header file in C++/CLI project, which contains some strings in different languages.
arabic, english, german, chinese, french, japanese etc...

I have a second project written in C#. 
Here I access the strings stored in the header file of the C++/CLI project.

The encoding of the header file is Unicode - Codepage 1200 or UTF-8.
the visual studio editor is able to display the strings correctly.
At runtime I access these strings and assign them into a local String variable. 
Here I recognized that many strings are not shown correctly. Doesn't matter if I assign them or not. Accessing the original place (while debugging) shows me all the foreign strings with question marks. Especially chinese, just question marks.

Example : "So?e St?ange ?ext in Ch?n?se"
(This is not the best example, I know)

What is the problem?
I read that C# is by default UTF-16,
My header file containing the strings is UTF-16 or UTF-8.

I must be able to handle strings in different languages. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: show the code! Try to use the overload to detect marks

Comment: How do you read the C++ file from C#? A few lines of code will help pinpoint the issue.

Comment: The C++CLI project is referenced by my C# project.
the C++CLI contains sth like this:
literal String^ sText = "中國話的中國話的中國話的";

When I access sText from my C# project the content of sText looks like "??????????????????".
But when I take the chinese string above and put it into a local variable in my C# project like this:
String sLocalText = "中國話的中國話的中國話的";
The debugger can show the local one correctly but not the other one!

Answer (score -1):

The '?" means that the text is read as Unicode(UTF16) and somehwere there is a conversion to your current code page. Since your current codepage is NOT chinese the chinese chararcters will get transformed to '?'

It would be helpful to see the code.

Comment: Why would you need to see code to determine this? Seems like the answer would lie having to do with Unicode support, not code, itself.